# import_module stops working after __pycache__ is generated

Tags: python-3.x

I am importing modules dynamically

In my main file, in the project root, I do

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "mylib"))
```

In my command import file, `mylib/nogui/main.py` I do

```
commands_path = Path(__file__).parent.joinpath("command")
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk(commands_path):
    for file in filenames:
        if file.startswith("cmd_"):
            imported_module = import_module(f"mylib.nogui.command.{file[:file.find('.py')]}")
            imported_module.register()
```

inside `mylib.nogui.command` directory is the file `cmd_echo.py`:

```
def register():
    print("This works")
```

If I run my main file, the first time, I see:

```
This works
```

If I run it again, I see:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mylib.nogui.command.cmd_echo.cpython-37'; 'mylib.nogui.command.cmd_echo' is not a package

The only difference is the __pycache__ folder exists. If I delete this folder, it works as expected again.

Answer (score 0):

**The answer was `os.walk` is recursive by default**

The "This works" was still being output, but it was hidden by the error message. My mistake.

The target module (cmd_echo) **was** being imported, but then `os.walk` went into the __pycache__ folder and ran the dynamic import code there too, which spawned this error. The simple solution was to add a break after the first loop

```
commands_path = Path(__file__).parent.joinpath("command")
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk(commands_path):
    for file in filenames:
        if file.startswith("cmd_"):
            imported_module = import_module(f"rantlib.nogui.command.{file[:file.find('.py')]}")
            imported_module.register()
    break
```